# PHP Limit number of rown in table

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table, rows

I've got a fairly large database of users, and I wish to limit only about 15-20 rows for each page. And if it's not too much trouble. How am I going to make pages to continue surfing the whole table showing only 20 rows each page.

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['points']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['winratio']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['pointsratio']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['finishedmaps']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['lastseen']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You should really try to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) MySQL_* functions are deprecated, and in PHP 7 have been approved to removal...

Comment: What you are looking for is commonly called "pagination".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm
Change $rec_limit = 20 if you want 20 row each page

Comment: Thank you sir! This helped me greatly! ;) (y)